# cannot find symbol error en Java

Tags: java

estoy tratando de crear una clase "Buscador", cuyo uno de los atributos es otra clase ya creada llamada "Lector", pero al tratar de compilar la clase Buscador me da el error cannot find symbol, tengo una clase "Prueba" que tiene el main y todo funciona bien con Lector, el problema es Buscador. Ademas estoy usando java 11.

Código de clase Lector:

```
package Dependencias.Procesamineto;
import java.io.*;

public class Lector {
    private String cadena;
    private File archivo;

    public Lector(String direccion) {
        archivo = new File(direccion);
    }

    public void extraerCadena() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(archivo);
        InputStreamReader isIn = new InputStreamReader(fileIn);
        BufferedReader lector = new BufferedReader(isIn);
        cadena = lector.readLine();
        lector.close();
    }

    public String getCadena() {
        return cadena;
    }

    public void setCadena(String cadena) {
        this.cadena = cadena;
    }
}
```

Código de Buscador:

```
package Dependencias.Procesamineto;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Buscador {
    private Lector lector;
    private String cadena;
    private String [] arreglo;

    public Buscador(String direccion) throws FileNotFoundException ,IOException{
        lector = new Lector(direccion);
        try {
            lector.extraerCadena();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        cadena = lector.getCadena();
        arreglo = cadena.split(" ");
    }
}
```

Error en terminal:

```
Buscador.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
private Lector lector;
        ^
symbol:   class Lector
location: class Buscador
Buscador.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
       lector = new Lector(direccion);
                 ^
symbol:   class Lector
location: class Buscador
2 errors
```

¿Alguna idea de lo que este pasando?

Comment: Tienes que importar la clase. `import Dependencias.Lector;`

Comment: Ya lo intente y sigue dando el mismo error, cabe destacar que estoy usando vs code para editar y estoy compilando las clases en la terminal

Comment: Hola Bruno, a la hora de compilar debes hacerlo de la siguiente forma: **javac Lector.java Buscador.java **, dinos si lo haces así, o de que forma.

Comment: Que tal Marce, los intentaba compilar por separado, ya con la forma que me diste ya pude compilarlo.

Comment: Siempre que contestes un comentario, agrega en el mismo **@nombreUsuario**, para que el mismo sea notificado, si has solucionado tu problema, podrías publicar la solución , en la zona de respuestas, para ayudar a otros que tengan el mismo problema, y de paso, puede que te "lluevan" unos puntitos de reputación.